# How can I async await for an event in a child component? Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-router

I want to protect the user from navigating away from an unsaved form using a custom modal and vue-router.

This is possible with native browser alert box

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!') 
    if (answer) {
      next();
    } else { 
      next(false);
    }
}
```

but how can I wait for an event from a custom child modal component?

```
async beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    const a = await this.showModal();

    if (a) {
      next();
    } else {
      next(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`beforeRouteLeave` isn't promise-aware, a promise that `async` function returns is ignored.

`next` is a common name for a callback in JavaScript ecosystem. As [the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) shows, it accepts an argument. It should be:

```
async beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    const a = await this.showModal();

    if (a)
      next(); 
    else
      next(false); 
}
```

Comment: this is the correct syntax, I was just writing sudo code. will update my question

Comment: I see. Did you try exactly the same thing as I posted, `next(false)`? I'd expect the code to work, as long as `this.showModal()` works as expected. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: next(false); works fine, this.showModal(); only toggles the modal component with this.showModal = true; Trying to figure out how to wait for an event

Answer (score 0):

Got it working but not convinced this is the best solution:

First, save the `next` function as a data object

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
   if (this.$store.state.product.unsavedChanges) {
       this.nextObj = next; // save next function as a data object  
       this.showModal = true;
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

then in your modal component, emit an event and handle it on your parent component

```
<modal @continueOrCancel="continueOrCancel" />
```

Fire the function on your parent component

```
methods: {
  continueOrCancel(e) {
     if (e == "continue") {
        this.nextObj(); // works.
     } else {
        this.nextObj(false); // does not work. Only logs the next function. Also tried with string "false", and 0 which produces the same result. 
        this.showModal = false; // continue, but what about route lifecycle ??
     }
  }
}
```